# Haskell why does this type check

Tags: haskell, types

```
import Data.Monoid

newtype Constant a b =
    Constant { getConstant :: a }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Functor (Constant a) where
    fmap _ (Constant a) = Constant a

instance (Monoid a) => Applicative (Constant a) where
    pure x = Constant (mempty x )
    _ <*> (Constant a) = Constant a

--:t (<*>)
--(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

--:t Constant (Sum 1)
--Constant (Sum 1) :: Num a => Constant (Sum a) b

--Constant (Sum 1) <*> Constant (Sum 2)
--Constant { getConstant = Sum { getSum = 2 }}
```

My question is why does the last statement type check?

I expected the left side of <*> to be of type f ( a -> b)
Where 
  f = Constant 
  (a -> b) = Sum 1?

There's nothing I can apply to (Sum 1) because it is fully applied, yet this statement compiles.

Comment: In your definition `mempty x` works, though the type of `mempty` is `Monoid a => a`. Try replacing this definition with `pure x = Constant (mempty x x x x x x 127 "abc" () x x )`. Does it work? Why? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two type variables here:

```
newtype Constant a b =
    Constant { getConstant :: a }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

But you only "store" values of the first type, and the second is a [*phantom*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type).

But your `Applicative` instance is only concerned with the *second* type variable that you have -- the `b`, the elusive phantom.

That means that values like `Constant (Sum 1)` can have any sort of thing as their second type variable -- it doesn't matter! You can write:

```
foo :: Constant Sum (a -> b)
foo = Constant (Sum 1)

bar :: Constant Sum String
bar = Constant (Sum 1)

baz :: Constant Sum (IO [Maybe Int])
baz = Constant (Sum 1)
```

Because you never actually need a value of the phantom type.

Thus when you write `Constant (Sum 1) <*> Constant (Sum 2)`, the type checker infers the correct types:

```
let foo = Constant (Sum 1) :: Constant Sum (a -> b)
    bar = Constant (Sum 2) :: Constant Sum a
 in foo <*> bar
```

So the left-hand side of `<*>` *does* have the type `f (a -> b)`, but `f` is *`Constant Sum`*, not just `Constant`.

Comment: All excellent answers, I chose this because "f is Constant Sum" puts the nail in the coffin for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The left side *is* `f (a -> b)`.  This is correct.

Remember the type here (let's make `1 :: Int` for simplicity):

```
Constant (Sum 1) :: forall a. Constant (Sum Int) a
```

I've added the explicit `forall`.  The type checker can unify `a` with anything.

Try this one:

```
Constant (Sum 1) :: Constant (Sum Int) (a -> b)
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 4):

For `Const`:

```
(<*>) :: Const c (a -> b) -> Const c a -> Const c b
```

Your input was a `Const c (a -> b)` a `Const c a`.  You gave a `Const c b` in return -- if `x :: c`, then `Const x :: Const c a`, for any `a`.  It can be `Const c Int`, `Const c Bool`, etc.

For example:

```
Const "Hello" :: Const String Int
Const "Hello" :: Const String Bool
Const "Hello" :: Const String Double
Const "Hello" :: Const String a
Const "Hello" :: Const String (a -> b)
Const "Hello" :: Const String b
```

all typecheck, because the last parameter can be anything -- `"Hello"` only constrains the first parameter.

However, you should note that your `Applicative` instance doesn't obey the Applicative laws.

```
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
```

in particular is violated:

```
Const "hello" <*> pure 4
== Const "hello" <*> Const ""
== Const ""
```

but

```
pure ($ 4) <*> Const "hello"
== Const "" <*> Const "hello"
== Const "hello"
```

Comment: Good catch with the Applicative laws.

Comment: It seems Constant inherently breaks that applicative law.

Comment: @mac10688 not quite; it's possible to write a lawful Applicative instance for `Constant` :)

Comment: @mac10688 the main problem is that using `<*>` to "combine" effects is supposed to merge them together and also merge their effects.  The way you wrote it, your `<*>` loses effects/information from the left side.  How can you write it so that it incorporates both sides in the answer?

Comment: @JustinL. yes, the problem is that I'm reading the beta version of a haskell learning book. The examples given don't align with the real Const applicative instance. Someone in the IRC haskell channel demonstrated. I have written the book's authors to consider changing the examples.